# angular seed master running unit test?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, karma-runner

Im trying to run angular seed master running unit test?
this is what i have ...

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\angular-seed-master> scripts/test.bat

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\xampp\htdocs\angular-seed-master\node_modules\karma\lib\index.js/lib/cli'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
```

i have intall karma , node , and jasmine, but im not sure what this error is telling me

i have look at index.js and this is what it has

```
// index module
exports.VERSION = require('./constants').VERSION;
exports.server = require('./server');
exports.runner = require('./runner');
exports.launcher = require('./launcher');
```

Not sure why im getting this error. I'm running this on windows 7. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have figure out the problem, I forgot to put node in front first.
for example: node scripts/web-server.js